# Parse JSON string in android

Tags: java, android, json

What I want to do is process live currency JSON strings and retrieve their rate values.

The site I am using returns this:

```
{"target": "EUR", "success": true, "rate": 0.7298, "source": "USD", "amount": 0.73, "message": ""}
```

for a URL:

```
http://currency-api.appspot.com/api/USD/EUR.json?key=KEY
```

For a conversion of USD to Euros. I want to store the rate in a float. I realise I will have to use GSON or something similar to parse the JSON output of the site, but so far I don't have a solution that works. My current AsyncTask for this looks like this:

```
        class AsyncTest extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://currency-api.appspot.com/api/USD/EUR.json?key=KEY");
                URLConnection connect = url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
                String jsonObject = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                    jsonObject += line;
                in.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);;
        }

    }
```

What exactly is wrong here? It causes a runtime exception. And how would I parse the rate out of this URL?

Comment: What is the runtime exception? Post the stack trace. There are tons of JSON parsing examples out there.

Comment: You should use StringBuilder instead of String, it is faster : jsonObject .append(line);

Comment: Consider using the [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidquery) library to easily get the data, then parse using the method `$.map(json)`, which converts a `JSONObject` to a `HashMap` for easy parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class AsyncTest extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://currency-api.appspot.com/api/USD/EUR.json?key=KEY");
            URLConnection connect = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder jsonObject = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                jsonObject.append( line );
            in.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonObject.toString());
            ///// Parse the Json object right here using getString

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);;
    }

}
```

To parse the JSON object, look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

For example

```
private void parseJson(JSONObject json){
    String target = json.getString("target");
    boolean success = json.getBoolean("success");
    // If the field is optional, use optXXX
    double rate = json.optDouble("rate", 1d);
    ......

}
```

Comment: Here's an [android example for parsing JSON](http://android.codota.com/scenarios/528e1e7dda0a36cf485bcf50/JSONObject.getString?tag=bumblebee)

Answer (score 0):

try catching the JSONException .

Comment: the OP isn't creating a JSONObject anywhere, so no JSONException will be thrown